# How can I track new questions with specific keywords?

Tags: support

I am thinking about getting into answering more heavily. But for that, I need a tool to filter questions for which I know answers. Is there such a tool available openly? How can I track new questions on Stack Overflow that have specific keywords? The list of keywords may be long. It would be convenient to receive emails on such questions.

Let's say I am interested in answering questions related to Rust. I am not an expert in all fields related to [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust). I am proficient in some. It's not time-efficient to watch all questions related to tag Rust. I am sure most experienced Stack Overflow users use some automation. Doesn't anyone want to share it? Is that something forbidden?

Comment: Do you mean tags when you say specific keywords?

Comment: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: I mean receiving email if a new question have any keyword instead of reading all questions.

Comment: Not tag. Keywords in the text.

Comment: It's better if you watch tags. It's going to be more effective for you.

Comment: Then "no" there isn't. That's what tags are for. It seems unlikely that your "keywords" would not equate to tags.

Comment: *"I need a tool to filter in questions for which I know answers."* Don't we all, but a keyword would not guarantee you know the answer...

Comment: Let's say I am interested in answering questions related to Rust. I am not an expert in all fields related to tag Rust. I am proficient in some. It's not time-efficient to watch all questions related to tag Rust. I am sure most experienced stack overflow users use some automation. Doesn't anyone want to share it? Is that something forbidden?

Comment: You can combine tags, and use custom filters.

Comment: @yivi is that possible to setup receiving an email on a new question satisfying criteria?

Comment: *"I am not an expert in all fields related to tag Rust."* Then add the technologies, in Rust, you aren't familiar with to your ignore list. I'm a (self claimed) expert in SQL Server, which frequently gets tagged with things like [[tag:entity-framework]], which I know nothing about; so the tag is in my ignored tags. I also have other RDBMS in my ignored tags, so that I can easily spot questions where people tag spam and don't know what they are using (and I often promptly remove all the conflicting tags so the OP can edit and tag correctly).

Comment: There's also [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=featured&q=search)

Comment: It sounds like the ideal application for a *[Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/about)* [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app?tab=Votes) or [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script?tab=Votes). I don't know if one already exists for this purpose or not. Have a look.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you. Good finding.

Comment: Can you perhaps give an example of a keyword search you feel would be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most effective strategy for this would be to use tags.

You can watch specific tags, and create custom filters that match a combination of tags:

[image]

[image]

The saved filter will appear on your sidebar, and will be marked with a red dot when there are new questions that match your criteria.

I don't think you can currently receive emails for custom filters... or at least I couldn't find the way.

The appropriate section on user settings (settings -> edit email settings -> question subscriptions):

[image]

... takes me to an empty page on my network profile, where I don't see any way to add a new "subscription":

[image]

I don't know if it's just broken, or I'm misusing the tool

Personally, I rather click on my custom filters when I see a red dot and check if any of the latest questions is worth answering (or deserves any kind of vote), than receive emails about it. This way I can see what's new when I'm actually available to act on it.

Comment: In addition you can add tags with wildcards e.g `rust*` to watch anything related to `rust`

Comment: @SurajRao TIL. Thanks for that! I wasn't aware of this and could really use it

Comment: @Larnu I am able to add a custom filter with `rust*` . It loads `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust*?sort=Newest&uqlId=49230`

Comment: Interesting, so you can use the URL to build the filter, thanks @SurajRao . The list at the top [looks "beautiful"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*+or+ssms*+or+tsql?sort=Newest&uqlId=49232). ;)

Comment: Well, watch anything whose tag starts with `rust`, @SurajRao. It may or may not be related to the Rust language. Imagine a `rustly.js` tag about some JavaScript package.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes one of the negatives of wildcards. You may have to add in ignore I suppose.